# Can't type single or double quote before i,o,a and similar characters

Tags: macos, osx-lion, keyboard-layout

I'm using OsX Lion 10.7.4 version. Anyway when I try to type single quote then i, it prints í .. when i try to type double quote then i , it prints ï .. Looks like it's a setting but couldn't find how to change it.

It looks like;

```
Acute  ´    option e + the character    Á É Í Ó Ú á é í ó ú
```

But I'm not pressing option key.. Just pressing İ key on turkish layout with US English keyboard(Virtually)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Ok I fixed it, using US keyboard not US International is the solution.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I fixed it, using US keyboard not US International is the solution.